# buildah: unknown shorthand flag: 'i' in -i

Tags: podman, buildah

If I am to launch a container with podman I can use the `-ti` flags to connect my terminal to the container,

```
$ podman run -ti centos:7 /bin/sh
sh-4.2# exit
```

But the same option I build with buildah it returns

```
$ buildah run -ti $(buildah from centos:7) /bin/sh
unknown shorthand flag: 'i' in -i
```

What is the right method to invoke buildah?

Answer (score 2):

Buildah combines `-t` and `-i` together into its own `-t` (or `--tty`) that allocates and connects to stdin.

> `-t`, `--tty`, `--terminal` By default a pseudo-TTY is allocated only when buildah's standard input is attached to a pseudo-TTY.  Setting the **`--tty` option to true will cause a pseudo-TTY to be allocated inside the container connecting the user's "terminal" with the stdin and stdout stream of the container.**  Setting the `--tty` option to false will prevent the pseudo-TTY from being allocated.

Compared to `podman` ,

> `--tty`, `-t=true|false` **Allocate a pseudo-TTY.** The default is false.
>
> `--interactive`, `-i=true|false` When set to true, **keep stdin open** even if not attached. The default is false.